# Проблемы с запросом к базе данных MySQL

Tags: php, kohana, select, mysql

Добрый всем день.

Делаю функцию на кохане, проверяющую строку ID - пустая она или в ней находится число.

```
$query = DB::select('id')->from('sessions')->where('session_id', '=', $session_id)->limit(1)->execute();
```

В итоге нужно получить либо true, если ID не пустая, либо false - если в ID ничего нет. Какую проверку можно сделать, чтобы это определить?

Comment: Нужно смотреть что находится в переменной `$query` после запроса.

Answer (score 0):

что то типо такого:

```
$query = DB::select('id')->from('sessions')->where('session_id', '=', $session_id)->limit(1)->execute()?true:false;
```